# Setup WiFi on Pi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) to setup WiFi on my Pi. But it doesn't work.
Can someone help?

Here are some debug outputs.

```
os: Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux


journalctl | grep wlan0
Apr 25 15:36:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Apr 25 15:36:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[404]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Apr 25 15:36:11 raspberrypi kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: IAID eb:49:49:eb
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: adding address fe80::676a:712f:8132:7eca
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: carrier lost
Apr 25 15:36:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::676a:712f:8132:7eca
```

---

```
ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4354:a1df:b8d:9509  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:1c:1c:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8684  bytes 12555005 (11.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4660  bytes 338811 (330.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 352 (352.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 352 (352.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:49:49:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=SI

network={
        ssid="MYWIFI"
        psk="*********"
}
```

---

```
sudo iwconfig
enxb827eb1c1cbe  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

**Update**

Today I create mobile hotspot and pi could connect. So it must be router issue. Anyone know what could be wrong on router side.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6c7b:1dd0:3a7b:ca3e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:1c:1c:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46  bytes 7411 (7.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 73  bytes 10639 (10.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::424:428e:6818:96c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:49:49:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8  bytes 1073 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 5827 (5.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

**Update 2**

I tried *Raspbian Stretch with desktop and recommended software* version.
Then I installed XRDP server and connected via RDP. After I connected to WiFi through GUI my Pi can automatically connect to Wifi.
What can be a problem that I couldn't connect before?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using Raspbian Stretch with Desktop?

Comment: @CoderMike No. Stretch Lite.

Answer (score 1):

Just for testing your network environment please flash a new image [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2019-04-08](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and boot it in your RasPi. Then create your `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the `/boot/` directory, **not** in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/`. It should look like this:

```
rpi ~$ cat /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=SI

network={
        ssid="MYWIFI"
        psk="*********"
}
```

Now reboot.

If you do **not** have a working wifi connection to **MYWIFI** after reboot then it is not a general problem with the setup. Either you have made a typo or the RasPi is broken or you have used a wrong password or your internet router is misconfigured or something like this. Don't modify the setup on the RasPi. It should work without typos.

Comment: I did fresh install, but it doesn't work. Maybe it is router problem. But no device currently no device has problem with WiFi connection.

Comment: @usil On the other side hundreds of users don't have a problem with the setup described in the answer.

Comment: I updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. 
The following line was missing in *wpa_supplicant.conf*.

```
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

---

The whole file must looks like this.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=SI

network={
        ssid="MYWIFI"
        psk="*********"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```